# fetch data from table where if condition is true all related rows hides

Tags: mysql

i have a table as below:

```
--------------------------------------
   id    |   product_id   |   value
--------------------------------------
   1     |       1        |     1
   2     |       1        |     2       
   3     |       1        |     3
   4     |       2        |     1
   5     |       2        |     2
```

now i want that i select data and if in where condition, value!=3 then result should not have rows where product id is 1 because it contains value = 3

hope you understand.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
product_id NOT IN 
(SELECT product_id FROM mytable WHERE
 value=3)`

There is a nested query in this. In the nested query you find all product_id's which has value 3, this returns 1. Then in your first query you find the product that are **NOT** in the returned query. So product_id's which are not 1.

This query returns rows with id's 4 and 5.